# How to convert a Datetime String into a Datetime object

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-format, datetime-parsing

`string DateCreated = "2012-05-24 12:34:40.060";` USA culture

How do I create the string into a Date time object with a format that include the month,
day, year, hour, minutes, seconds, milliseconds.
I think the format is this "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt" but not sure.
** ** = underline in red, its an error

I need the datetime object because I want to pass it through another function that only accept a value of "DateTime" and not a string

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank You

this is what I have so far but i know its wrong

```
  string DateCreated = "2012-05-24 12:34:40.060";
  DateTime dt = **new DateTime(DateCreated);** 
  DateTime dateCreated = **dateCreated.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff tt")**;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(DateCreated, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff");
```

Comment: is that dateTime now a dateTime object?

Comment: yes, you can assign it to `DateTime` type variable or use it as a parameter for a method that uses `DateTime`..

Comment: The format is incorrect. Also, when you're not specifying the format, you really should specify the culture

Comment: I need the datetime object because I want to pass it through another function that only accept a value of "DateTime" and not a string

Comment: @Yusuf the dateTime object is of type DateTime. You really really really should read some basic programming tutorials

Comment: @ŁukaszW.pl It is the format he provided. He also states that he knows that it is incorrect. And it doesn't work for his input

Comment: @Yusuf - yes.. `DateTime.Parse` methods returns the `DateTime` object that you can use in youre method...

Comment: @OskarKjellin and suggestions for me to read. I would appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

```
string dateCreated = "2012-05-24 12:34:40.060";
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateCreated, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff",
                                       System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

you can also use

```
Convert.ToDateTime Method (String)
```

Comment: You know how u explicitly put "2012-05-24 12:34:40.060". What if I don't know what the date will be.

Comment: +1 Yes, the comma is wrong. A . (point) is right, but probably is just a typo

Comment: @Yusuf Once again, read some basic programming tutorials. Just replace that constant string with a variable

Comment: yeah it was a typo.. Thx for the correction..  @Yusuf yeah you can pass the string variable there.

Comment: Did you fix the comma situation?